# After refreshing the page I lose the ability to retrieve user information through Auth0 API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0

At first my webapp looses login after refresh, then I read some topics on how to set up social logins and I solved.
But now I have a different problem. Here is some code to explain better:

```
const { user } = useAuth0();

const sub = user.sub;
```

If I refresh I get: “*TypeError: Cannot read property ‘sub’ of undefined*”
However, the user is still logged, in fact if I go back and then forward using the browser arrows, the page reloads without errors. 
If I load login/signup page url, the “logout” button appears as the user is still logged.
I realized that maybe it’s not clear. The button if the user is not logged display "login", if user is logged display “logout”.

From other tests I have done I have noticed this. If I refresh a component (use React.js) that retrieve user info like: `user.name`, `user.sub` ecc… I get error; but if I load a different component first and then the one using `user.` then it works.

Concrete example: The UserInfo.js component crashes after the refresh, but if I first access the Dashboard.js component and then click on UserInfo through the sidebar then it works and load it without any error.

How can I avoid this error? And above all why does it occur if the user apparently has not logged out?

EDIT: I think I have identified the problem but I don’t know how to solve it: when the page is rendered, the response from the Auth0 API still not obtained and therefore the claim `user.sub` is undefined.

Comment: would you mind sharing the code? commonly `useEffect` is used to synchronize state data from network

Comment: Yes, I use `useEffect` but the error is not there. The problem is in `const sub = user.sub`.
It can be simplified even without using `useEffect`. Ex: `<div> {sub} </div>`. With this code I can display the sub property in my React component. When I press refresh I get the error. As I wrote I think that after the refresh `user` is fetched after the component rendering and therefore it's `undefined`.